# reqwestで要素が取得できなかった場合にデータベースのレコードを削除したい。

Tags: rust

actix-webを利用してWebアプリを作成しています。
actix-webのハンドラ内で`reqwest`を使い、データベースに保存されているレコードのURLにアクセスし、結果が得られなかった場合そのレコードを削除するという処理を実装したいと考え以下のコードを実装しましたがエラーが出てしまいました。

コード

```
async fn valid_site(url: &str) -> Result<models::NewBackend, reqwest::Error>{
    let backend = reqwest::get(&format!("{}/.well-known/site.json", url))
        .await?
        .json()
        .await?;
    Ok(backend)
}

#[get("/backends/{id}")]
async fn backends_update(hb: web::Data<Handlebars>, pool: web::Data<DbPool>, id: web::Path<String>) -> Result<HttpResponse, Error>{
    let conn = pool.get().expect("cant get db pool");
    let id_int: i32 = id.parse().unwrap();
    let backend = web::block(move || actions::find_backend(&id_int, &conn))
        .await
        .map_err(|e| {
            eprintln!("{}", e);
            let body = hb.render("error", &json!({
                "reason": "Bad request"
            })).unwrap();
            HttpResponse::BadRequest().body(body)
        }
    )?;

    if let Some(backend) = backend{
        let site_info = valid_site(&backend.backend_url)
            .await
            .map_err(|e| async {
                eprintln!("{}", e);
                // リクエストに失敗した場合はレコードを削除する。
                web::block(move || actions::delete_backend(&id_int, &conn))
                    .await
                    .map_err(|e| {
                        eprintln!("{}", e);
                        let body = hb.render("error", &json!({
                            "reason": "Unexpected error occurred"
                        })).unwrap();
                        HttpResponse::InternalServerError().body(body)
                    })?;
                HttpResponse::SeeOther().header(http::header::LOCATION, "/").finish()
            }
        )?;

        let conn = pool.get().expect("cant get db pool");
        web::block(move || actions::update_backend(&backend.id, &site_info.name, &site_info.frontend_url, &site_info.backend_url, &site_info.description, &conn))
            .await
            .map_err(|e| {
                eprintln!("{}", e);
                let body = hb.render("error", &json!({
                    "reason": "Unexpected error occurred"
                })).unwrap();
                HttpResponse::InternalServerError().body(body)
            }
        )?;


        Ok(HttpResponse::SeeOther().header(http::header::LOCATION, "/").finish())
    }else{
        let body = hb.render("error", &json!({
            "reason": "not found backend"
        })).unwrap();
        Ok(HttpResponse::NotFound().body(body))
    }
}
```

エラー

```
error[E0277]: the `?` operator can only be used in an async block that returns `Result` or `Option` (or another type that implements `std::ops::Try`)
   --> src/main.rs:108:17
    |
105 |                .map_err(|e| async {
    |   ________________________________-
106 |  |                 eprintln!("{}", e);
107 |  |                 // リクエストに失敗した場合はレコードを削除する。
108 |  |                 web::block(move || actions::delete_backend(&id_int, &conn))
    |  |_________________^
109 | ||                     .await
110 | ||                     .map_err(|e| {
111 | ||                         eprintln!("{}", e);
...   ||
115 | ||                         HttpResponse::InternalServerError().body(body)
116 | ||                     })?;
    | ||_______________________^ cannot use the `?` operator in an async block that returns `actix_http::response::Response`
117 |  |                 HttpResponse::SeeOther().header(http::header::LOCATION, "/").finish()
118 |  |             }
    |  |_____________- this function should return `Result` or `Option` to accept `?`
    |
    = help: the trait `std::ops::Try` is not implemented for `actix_http::response::Response`
    = note: required by `std::ops::Try::from_error`

error[E0277]: the trait bound `impl std::future::Future: actix_http::error::ResponseError` is not satisfied
   --> src/main.rs:119:10
    |
119 |         )?;
    |          ^ the trait `actix_http::error::ResponseError` is not implemented for `impl std::future::Future`
    |
    = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `std::convert::From<impl std::future::Future>` for `actix_http::error::Error`
    = note: required by `std::convert::From::from`

error: aborting due to 2 previous errors
```

実行環境

- rustc 1.41.0 (5e1a79984 2020-01-27)
- actix-web = "2.0.0"
- actix-rt = "1.0.0"
- diesel = {version = "1.4.3", features = ["sqlite", "r2d2"]}
- dotenv = "0.15.0"
- r2d2 = "0.8.8"
- serde = { version = "1.0", features = ["derive"] }
- serde_json = "1.0"
- env_logger = "0.7.1"
- reqwest = { version = "0.10", features = ["json"] }
- tokio = { version = "0.2", features = ["full"] }
- handlebars = "2.0.0"

このようなことをする場合どういったAPIを利用すればよいのでしょうか。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

エラーになる理由ですが、`map_err()`メソッドに渡しているクロージャの戻り値型と、そのクロージャ内にある`?`後置演算子が要求する戻り値型が一致しないためです。

- 該当のコードでは、`Result`型の`map_err()`メソッドは、クロージャの戻り値型が`Error`であることを要求する
- `?`後置演算子はクロージャの戻り値型が`Result`型か`Option`型であることを常に要求する

`?`演算子はクロージャ内ではうまく使えないことが多いです。今回のようなケースでは`?`演算子もクロージャも使わずに、`match`/`if let`と`return`を組み合わせるのがお勧めです。

`let site_info = ...` のところを、以下のように書き換えてみてください。これでコンパイルできるはずです。

```
let site_info = match valid_site(&backend.backend_url).await {
    Ok(info) => info, // Ok(..) なら値をアンラップする
    Err(e) => {
        eprintln!("{}", e);
        // リクエストに失敗した場合はレコードを削除する。
        let response = web::block(move || actions::delete_backend(&id_int, &conn))
            .await
            // delete_backend から OK(_) が返されたなら、その中身を HttpResponse で置き換える
            .map(|_| HttpResponse::SeeOther().header(http::header::LOCATION, "/").finish())
            // delete_backend から Err(e) が返されたなら、それを丸ごと Ok(HttpResponse) で置き換える
            .or_else(|e| {
                eprintln!("{}", e);
                let body = hb.render("error", &json!({
                    "reason": "Unexpected error occurred"
                })).unwrap();
                Ok(HttpResponse::InternalServerError().body(body))
            });
        // 早期リターンする
        return response;  // Result<HttpResponse, Error>型
    }
};
```

**追記**

> `actions::delete_backend`については`map`と`or_else`で書かれていていますが、これも`match`を使って書くことができますか。

`match`式でも書けます。その場合、`let site_info = ...`のところは以下のようになります。

```
let site_info = match valid_site(&backend.backend_url).await {
    Ok(info) => info, // Ok(..) なら値をアンラップする
    Err(e) => {
        eprintln!("{}", e);
        // リクエストに失敗した場合はレコードを削除する。
        let response = match web::block(move || actions::delete_backend(&id_int, &conn)).await {
            // delete_backend から OK(..) が返されたなら、Ok(HttpResponse) を返す
            Ok(_) => Ok(HttpResponse::SeeOther().header(http::header::LOCATION, "/").finish()),
            // delete_backend から Err(..) が返されたなら、Ok(HttpResponse) を返す
            Err(e) => {
                eprintln!("{}", e);
                let body = hb.render("error", &json!({
                    "reason": "Unexpected error occurred"
                })).unwrap();
                Ok(HttpResponse::InternalServerError().body(body))
            }
        };
        return response;  // Result<HttpResponse, Error>型
    }
};
```

実は`map()`や`or_else()`などのメソッドは`match`式で実装されています。APIドキュメントでは各関数・メソッドの右側に`[src]`というリンクがあって、そこから実装を見ることができます。

`Result::map()`の実装
https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html#method.map

```
#[inline]
#[stable(feature = "rust1", since = "1.0.0")]
pub fn map<U, F: FnOnce(T) -> U>(self, op: F) -> Result<U,E> {
    match self {
        Ok(t) => Ok(op(t)),
        Err(e) => Err(e)
    }
}
```

`Result::or_else()`の実装
https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html#method.or_else

```
#[inline]
#[stable(feature = "rust1", since = "1.0.0")]
pub fn or_else<F, O: FnOnce(E) -> Result<T, F>>(self, op: O) -> Result<T, F> {
    match self {
        Ok(t) => Ok(t),
        Err(e) => op(e),
    }
}
```

Rustに慣れないうちは、`let site_info = ...`の最後の例のように、`map()`などを使わずに`match`式で書いたほうがいいかもしれません。そのほうがコード量は増えますが、わかりやすくなると思います。

Comment: ありがとうございます。`actions::delete_backend`についてはmapとor_elseで書かれていていますが、これもmatchを使って書くことができますか。